# Correct way to import file from different directory in Cython

Tags: python, include, cython

I have a .pxd file which contains declaration of a variable in another c header file as can be understood from the following code:

```
cdef extern from "parameters.h":
    ctypedef struct mm_np:
        int nlay
        double n1
        double n2[3]
        double d[3]
        double n3
        int lut
```

when the file parameters.h is in the same folder that the cythonizing script is running - everything goes perfect.

**Question**:
How to do the same include when the file "parameters.h" is in different directory and not the one that the .pxd file is in?

I tried to replace the first line of this code with

```
cdef extern from "/liboptv/include/parameters.h":
```

that doesn't work and when I cythonize I get a message that the file is not found:

> fatal error: /liboptv/include/parameters.h: No such file or directory

Thanks.

Comment: Hmh, I have never tried that, but I think you should go a different way here. Instead of trying to give a full path, try adding the directory to the custom header files to the compiler options. IIRC, there is a include_dirs option when declaring Extension modules in your setup.py file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented above, it is more robust to include the path to the headers' directory in one of the ways:

- `-I` compiler option
- `include_dirs` setuptools parameters
- `INCLUDE` environment variable

you can also use relative imports from one path which is included in one of the options above. For example, if you want to include the headers:

```
/usr/include/test/soft1/mod1/header1.h
/usr/include/test/soft1/mod2/header2.h
/usr/include/test/soft1/mod3/header3.h
```

You can add a subfolder that embodies all these paths:

```
gcc ... -I/usr/include/test/soft1
```

and in Cython use relative imports:

```
cdef extern from "mod1/header1.h":
...
cdef extern from "mod2/header1.h":
```

and so forth.